# Unable to read csv file from the build folder , that get created while I run my post requests

Tags: scala-gatling

I am trying to read data from csv file for my patch and delete requests. I am not adding a csv file by myself, it is getting  generated after the completion of my post requests in the build folder with the path resources/test/data/"****".csv .
Earlier when I was using dependencies as follows, it was working fine:-

```
testCompile group: 'io.gatling.highcharts', name: 'gatling-charts-highcharts', version: '2.2.5'
testCompile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12'
compile "org.scalaj:scalaj-http_2.11:2.3.0"
compile group: 'com.github.tototoshi', name: 'scala-csv_2.11', version: '1.2.2'
```

But now when i updated my application as follows :-

```
testCompile group: 'io.gatling.highcharts', name: 'gatling-charts-highcharts', version: '3.3.1'
testCompile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10'
compile "org.scalaj:scalaj-http_2.11:2.4.2"
compile group: 'com.github.tototoshi', name: 'scala-csv_2.12', version: '1.3.6'
```

it is giving me the error as

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate feeder file: Resource ******.csv not found
at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport.separatedValues(FeederSupport.scala:45)
at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport.separatedValues$(FeederSupport.scala:40)
at io.gatling.core.Predef$.separatedValues(Predef.scala:24)
at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport.csv(FeederSupport.scala:34)
at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport.csv$(FeederSupport.scala:33)
at io.gatling.core.Predef$.csv(Predef.scala:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is a mess as you have libraries compiled against Scala 2.11 (scalaj-http_2.11) and Scala 2.12 (scala-library:2.12.10, gatling-charts-highcharts:3.3.1).

You need to have Scala 2.12 everywhere.

Then, you file can't be located. It should be in `src/test/resources`. Where have you placed it? Have you checked for possible typos?

Comment: I tried using                                                           
testCompile group: 'io.gatling.highcharts', name: 'gatling-charts-highcharts', version: '3.3.1'
    testCompile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10'
    compile "org.scalaj:scalaj-http_2.12:2.4.2"
    compile group: 'com.github.tototoshi', name: 'scala-csv_2.12', version: '1.3.6'   But this did not worked